# How to add additional fields to drupal login form?

Tags: jquery, drupal, authentication

I am getting the form using :

```
$elements = drupal_get_form("user_login");
```

How can I add new elements to the form ? Like I want to add hyperlinks. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HOOK_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or even [HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)